# Azure Data Factory Power Query error: "We could not evaluate this query due to invalid or missing credentials

Tags: azure-data-factory, powerquery

In Azure Data Factory v2, I'm trying to create a Power Query  (ADF). I'm using Parquet to consume the dataset.
Within the dataset, I can successfully preview the data.

But in power query I am getting error

> We could not evaluate this query due to invalid or missing credentials

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be any of the following reasons, please check once.

1. Use of parameterized linked service which is not supported in Power Query
2. Use of unsupported authentication type
3. System issue.

**Possible Workaround**

Remove and re-add the Power Query

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/757093/azure-data-factory-power-query-error-34we-could-no.html

Comment: The power query feature is not available in South India, according to Microsoft support. that's why it isn't working.